# Why will this not display the appropriate data associated with the Select query?

Tags: php, pdo

My end goal is to hjave a simple web app that we can enter paper/toner usage, and runs reports. It is nothing complex, and serves to allow me to learn php. I am using PDO for the database work. I made the insert function work perfectly, but for the life of me, I cannot get the below statement to run. All I want to do is take the data, and then display it on an html form. MySQL is really really easy, but PDO is giving me a headache (I have searched everywhere, and cannot find a unified method to accomplish what I want)

```
include 'dbconnector.php';
$pastdate = $_POST['date'];

if (isset($_POST['datepull'])){
$pulldata = ("SELECT Paper, Black, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Blacksp, Cyansp, 
    Magentasp, Yellowsp FROM tablename WHERE Date = :date"):                          
$getdata = $database_connector->prepare($pulldata);
$getdata->bindParam(':date', $pastdate);
$getdata->execute();
$row = $getdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print $row['Paper']. "\t";

}
else {
echo "It didnt work again";
}
```

Comment: What prints...Please?

Answer (score 1):

Yo have a colon (`:`) instead of a semicolon (`;`) after the sql string. Besides date is a keyword, I think your `date` value should be a string.

Try this:

```
$getdata->bindParam(':date', $pastdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Hope it helps.